# iptables: redirect local request with NAT

Tags: networking, iptables, nat

I'd like to redirect local requests to port which is translated with NAT. I have following rules:

```bsh
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9020 -j DNAT --to 10.0.3.11:80
```

however request coming from localhost are rejected:

```
wget http://127.0.0.1:9020
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:9020... failed: Connection refused.
```

When I'm connecting from any other computer it works. Is there a way how to do this without recompiling kernel with `CONFIG_IP_NF_NAT_LOCAL=y`? https://wiki.debian.org/Firewalls-local-port-redirection (which seems to be obsolete).

Update:

`iptables -L -v -n --line-numbers -t nat`:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 26 packets, 3230 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source            destination    
4       0   0     DNAT      tcp  --  *       *      0.0.0.0/0         0.0.0.0/0   tcp dpt:9020 to:10.0.3.11:80

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source                destination         
1        0     0 MASQUERADE all  --  *       *      10.0.0.0/16           0.0.0.0/0
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on @Hauke Laging comments I put together this:

```bsh
# connections from outside
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9020 -j DNAT --to 10.0.3.11:80
# for local connection
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 9020 -j DNAT --to 10.0.3.11:80

# Masquerade local subnet
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.3.0/16 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -o lxcbr0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i lxcbr0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i lxcbr0 -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

where `lxcbr0` is interface in `10.0.3.0/16` subnet and `eth0` is interface with public IP addrees.

Comment: I've been looking for this for a long time (a couple of half hours)!!!